# Chrome not honoring Content-Disposition Attachment directive

Tags: java, google-chrome, browser, content-disposition

The desired behavior of the application is to prompt the user for a download location while providing a default filename which works great in IE & FF but Chrome always forces it to the download directory automatically.

I'm aware that chrome has the option in Settings > Advanced > "Ask where to save each file before downloading" The downside to this option is it applies globally across all pages whereas there are other items I have tested which we want to follow the inline behavior as a result those cases are in direct conflict with each other.

I searched around but couldn't find anything definitive stating it was or was not possible in Chrome but I find it odd that a behavior that has existed for so long and has multiple RFC's attached to it is not adhered to by Chrome which is always billed as being so standards compliant.
Here is how the headers are being received in the browsers as per Chrome dev tools

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint    
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="presentation.ppt"    
Content-Language: en-US    
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 13 Jan 2015 19:18:27 GMT
Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
```

Here is the code that sets the header server side

```
public void generatePowerPoint(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response){
    String id = (String) session.getAttribute(ApplicationConstants.ID);
    SlideShow ppt = reportService.generatePowerPoint(id);
    try{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("presentation_").append(id).append(".ppt");

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sb.toString()+ "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ppt.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        logger.error("The ppt could not be generated: ", e);
    }
}
```

Anyone have any input? Is it not possible? Workaround? If you need more detail let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Content-Disposition: attachment implies saving as attachment; not necessarily prompting where to save. I don't see what's wrong with Chrome's behavior.

Also, a nit: your code will generate broken header fields if the file name contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do question the behavior of attachment in this case.  The way I am reading [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) and [RFC 6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.2) the behavior of a file with a dispotion-header would be to prompt with a Save As dialog. Only little interesting note I found was regarding a MIME type specifally of application/octet-stream in conjunction with attachment should also behave this way.  Perhaps Chrome is not behaving since my type is set as application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

Comment: Just for completeness sake; changing the header to Content-Type:application/octet-stream did not change the behavior in Chrome.

Comment: hey @munkyxtc any success with your attempts?Same problem for me :(

Comment: @MuthuRaman I never fixed the issue the way I had set out. after much reading on the topic it seemed like a lost cause.  Chrome by default will save it to their download directory.  There is a setting found in Chrome to prompt the each time where to save but since I don't have access to each computer nor the want to have every single download to prompt the setting was worthless.  I just opted to allow the browser interpret it is as configured. In the last year since posted more browsers appear to be following this same sort logic.  Even new versions of IE automatically download it regardless.